# Disabled option from select box if already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a `table` with id = `fields-list` and inside this `table` `4` select box with the same class `db-list`. Now I want if the `option` in first `select` is selected disable this `option` in the rest of selectbox

```
<table id="fields-list" class="table table-hover">
   <select class="form-control db-list" >
       <option value="">All</option>
       <option value="d">1</option>
       <option value="t">2</option>
       <option value="t">3</option>
       <option value="h">4</option>
   </select>
   <select class="form-control db-list" >
       <option value="">All</option>
       <option value="d">1</option>
       <option value="t">2</option>
       <option value="t">3</option>
       <option value="h">4</option>
   </select>
</table>
```

I tried like this :

```
$('.db-list').on('change', function () {
  if( $('#fields-list').find('select option[value='+$(this).val()+']:selected').length>1){
      $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val()).prop('disabled', true);
  }           
});
```

But not work. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Situations how need to work :
1. First Select choose option 1 (all select box from the page should disable option 1);
2. Second Select choose option 3 (all select box from the page should disable option 3 + option 1 from previous selectd)
3. First Select choose option 4 (now all select box should disable option 4 + option 3 and enable option 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `table` should be changed to something else, `div` for example, because table should contain `thead`, `tbody` or `tr`
2. this line:

   `$(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val()).prop('disabled', true);`

will disable select, but not option, so try this:

```
$('#fields-list').find('select option[value='+$(this).val()+']:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
```

working example

```js
$('.db-list').on('focus', function () {
    var ddl = $(this);
    ddl.data('previous', ddl.val());
}).on('change', function () {
    var ddl = $(this);
    var previous = ddl.data('previous');
    ddl.data('previous', ddl.val());

    if (previous) {
        $('#fields-list').find('select option[value='+previous+']').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

    $('#fields-list').find('select option[value='+$(this).val()+']:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fields-list" class="table table-hover">
   <select class="form-control db-list" >
       <option value="">All</option>
       <option value="d">1</option>
       <option value="t">2</option>
       <option value="t">3</option>
       <option value="h">4</option>
   </select>
   <select class="form-control db-list" >
       <option value="">All</option>
       <option value="d">1</option>
       <option value="t">2</option>
       <option value="t">3</option>
       <option value="h">4</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Not work as expected.... For example in the first select I choose 1 in the second select I choose 2, when I go to the first select I want to chose 3 the option 1 should be active but is not the case

Comment: how I can activate the disabled option if was choosen another option from select ?

Comment: This is not work as **expected** because **expected** is not very clean from your question. Please share your tries to solve described problems. And may be create another question for it

Answer (score 2):

You can use .filter() to get options with a similar value

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('option').prop('disabled', false);
    $('select').each(function() {
        var val = this.value;
        $('select').not(this).find('option').filter(function() {
            return this.value === val;
        }).prop('disabled', true);
    });
}).change();
```

Comment: Perfect answer!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.db-list:first').on('change', function () {
    // enable all first
    $('.db-list:last option').prop('disabled', false);

    // disable the selected value
    $('.db-list:last option[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').prop('disabled', true);    

});
```

And by the way, `option`'s shouldn't have the same `value` in one `select` `option`.